# dynamically generated html buttons: source of onclick event caller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a DataTable which has a column like such:

```
string temp = row["date"].ToString();
rowDetail[0] = "<input type='button' onclick='showArchive(this)' value='" + temp + "'/>";
myTbl.Rows.Add(rowDetail);
```

So, when I bind myTbl to a datagrid.datasource, these column cells appear as buttons display "date" data. However, in my javascript function where the onclick event takes place, how would I know button/row made the call, so I can grab the rest of the data in that row for processing? I hope that's not lacking too much detail. Thanks all

**Edit:** Here's my js event:

```
function showArchive(btn)
    {
        __doPostBack('btnShowDates', '/*btn.gridRowIndex*/');
    }
```

Something like this would be ideal lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure JavaScript, but is is much easier if you use jQuery. This will give you the row data, assuming you're using a table:

```
function showArchive(element) {
   var myRow = $(element).parents('tr')
   $(myRow).find('td').each(function() {
      alert($(this).html())
   })   
}
```